# angular update ng-model by changing the DOM value of the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have a unique case where I need a DOM element value assignment to trigger the monitoring of an ng-model value.

In my HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="tracker.fileID_80" id="fileID_80" value="0">
```

Then in a JS function, change the value of the DOM element:

```
angular.element('#fileID_80')[0].value = 1 ;
```

And in the controller, use a $watch to track if the ng-model value has changed:

```
  var watchVar = $scope.$watch("tracker.fileID_80",function() {
  if ($scope.tracker.fileID_80 != 0) { 
    //
    // ... do something ...
    // 
    watchVar() ;    // kill the $watch
  }
```

I actually tried this code but the $watch did not detect any change in the ng-model's value...even though the DOM had updated the value to 1.   Yes, I know, this very hacky, but its a very unique situation that I need to try to figure out.  How can I make this work, or some variation of it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its possible for a DOM value change to trigger an ng-model change because I believe they are two separate control systems.   If someone can think of or share a solution I would be most interested.

However, I was able to create my own angluarJS $interval to watch for DOM changes and that did the trick:

In my HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="tracker.fileID_80" id="fileID_80" value="0">
```

Then in a JS function, change the value of the DOM element:

```
angular.element('#fileID_80')[0].value = 1 ;
```

And in the controller, use a $interval to check if the DOM element value has changed:

```
var watchID ;
var fileID = angular.element('#fileID_80')[0] ;
if (fileID.value == 0) {
  console.log("Interval Start") ;
  var watchCount = 0 ;
  watchID = $interval(function() {
    watchCount++ ;
    if (fileID.value != 0) {
      console.log("Element Changed:" +fileID.value) ;
      ... do something ...
      $interval.cancel(watchID) ;
    }
    // 30 second timeout
    if (watchCount == 60) {
      console.log("Interval Timeout")          
      $interval.cancel(watchID) ;
    }
  },500) ;
}
```

I wasn't expecting this to work but it does.  I thought I would need to do an addEventListener or something more intricate, but just watching for the element object value to change was sufficient.